# Проблемы с permissions на Android 6

Tags: android

При первом запуске приложения делаем запрос разрешения `Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, одобряю его, и пытаюсь получить изображение из галареи. При попытке что-то сделать с файлом, получаю

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/temporary_file.png: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Если перезапустить приложение, то разрешение повторно не запрашивается, так как оно уже подтверждено, и все работает как надо, файлы из галереи нормально достаются.

На текущий момент "проблема одного девайса", воспроизводится только у меня, и еще у одного человека. Но что-то мне подсказывает, что будут еще устройства с повторяющейся проблемой.

Воспроизводится на Nexus 5 c android 6.0 и 6.0.1
На нексусе 6 все ок работает.

**UPD**
Так же сделал [тестовый проект](https://github.com/rovkinmax/GalleryPicker/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/rovkinmax/gallerypicker/MainActivity.kt), на котором воспроизводится проблема

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В общем я выяснил, что это баг в прошивке.  [Подробное описание](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2982)

Пока я обошелся не совсем крутым решением, но рабочим.
Если выставить `targetSdkVersion 22`, то пермишены начинают работать постаринке.